# MySQL AVG wrong result with ELSE 0

Tags: mysql, sql

I am doing average on a column based on values of two other columns.

Table structure is like this

```
| rid | rate | status |....
|  1  | 1500 |   1    |....
|  1  | 1500 |   1    |....
|  1  | 1500 |   1    |....
|  1  | 1500 |   1    |....
|  2  | 1500 |   1    |....
```

When I do this way it gives me correct result `1500`, But it returns `NULL` for no `CASE` match, I need `AVG` to return `0` if no rows match the `CASE` condition.

```
AVG(CASE WHEN `rid` = `status` THEN `rate` END) DIV 1 AS `avg`
```

I tried this way but its giving me wrong result as `1200`

```
AVG(CASE WHEN `rid` = `status` THEN `rate` ELSE 0 END) DIV 1 AS `avg`
```

Why I am getting wrong result?

Please see and suggest any possible way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Would you please add records for which your are getting wrong answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
IFNULL(AVG(CASE WHEN `rid` = `status` THEN `rate` END) DIV 1,0) AS `avg`
```

Note : MySQL IFNULL takes two arguments, if first arguments is not null then it returns first arguments, otherwise it return second arguments

Comment: This is the same as my answer, only using the proprietary `IFNULL` instead of the standard `COALESCE` and even applying it wrong. Please see where you placed `,0)`. It should either come after the closing parenthesis of `AVG` or after `DIV 1`, not after the alias name.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT AVG(RATE) FROM TABLENAME GROUP BY rid,status
```

Try above query.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting 1200 because that last row where the case would return 0 would still count as a row , Hence **(1500*4 + 0)/5 = 1200** .

Answer (score 0):

The reason is based as case when filter the rows from the table
In the first select

```
  AVG(CASE WHEN `rid` = `status` THEN `rate` END) DIV 1 AS `avg`
```

the condition in case when  is executed  fo only 4 rows
do the fact that you have not else  condition the query is filter only for the matching  `rid` = `status`

In the second

```
AVG(CASE WHEN `rid` = `status` THEN `rate` ELSE 0 END) DIV 1 AS `avg`
```

the else clause implies the use also of the last  row (rid = 2) so you have 5 rows with 4 valid content for avg

Answer (score -1):

Apply `COALESCE` on your result:

```
COALESCE(AVG(CASE WHEN `rid` = `status` THEN `rate` END), 0) DIV 1 AS `avg`
```

Comment: Would the person who downvoted this, please explain why? The OP has a working formula (i.e. only treating rid=status records in the formula, leading to the correct value of 1500 for the sample data). Only that when there is no rid=status record, they get NULL instead of zero naturally. `COALESCE` turns the NULL into a zero and thus solves the problem. This is the standard way to do this and works in about all DBMS.

Comment: Sir your answer is more stranded approach, But I'll use `IFNULL` as its faster.

Comment: @Tall Boy: I don't mind that you prefer `IFNULL`, but I doubt that there is a measurable difference in speed. Can only be some nanoseconds I guess.